# Building GNU Binutils on MacOS Monterey fails

Tags: macos, gcc, binutils, macos-monterey

I'm trying to build binutils on my MacOS with Monterey 12.2.1 and XCOde 13.2.1 (with Command Line Tools for 13.2.1). I downloaded the binutils source code by cloning the repository

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
```

I independently downloaded the source for GMP (a dependency for binutils) and built and installed it similarly

```
mkdir build-gmp
cd build-gmp
../gmp_src/configure --prefix=$HOME/i386/
make && make install
```

Now for the binutils build

```
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-gdb/configure --prefix=$HOME/i386/ --target=i386-elf --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --with-gmp=$HOME/i386
make
```

The build proceeds for a bit and then fails with a compile error of

```
  CXX    linespec.o
../../binutils-gdb/gdb/linespec.c:4276:31: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'struct bound_minimal_symbol'
  struct bound_minimal_symbol mo = {minsym, objfile};
                              ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../binutils-gdb/gdb/minsyms.h:29:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
struct bound_minimal_symbol
       ^
../../binutils-gdb/gdb/minsyms.h:29:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
../../binutils-gdb/gdb/minsyms.h:29:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [linespec.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-gdb] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

For some reason it is invoke the C++ compiler to compile the C file and its complaining about the initialization which is legal C. I'm not sure how to force it to compile that file using C.

Has anyone recently attempted to compiled binutils and gcc for the Mac ? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to compile, instead of "brew install binutils" ?

Comment: Use of --target=i386-elf suggests you are building a 32-bit app. OS X Monterey doesn't support running 32 bit apps and xcode > 9 doesn't support building them, see [xcode 10 release notes, item 39858111](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-10-release-notes?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you compiling gdb?
Binutils and GDB have been merged so,
How about passing this to the `configure` file:

```
--disable-gdb
```

This will disable compilation for GDB.